# How to request undelivered messages in BotFramework?

Tags: botframework, skype, reliable-message-delivery

I can send a message to Skype user and I can receive message from him. But I can't get messages that user sent to bot while server is down.

For example, Facebook Messenger Platform [will resend the webhook event every 20 seconds, until a 200 OK response is received.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook) Viber also [used webhook](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#set-webhook-callback) url. But **Skype does not resend** to my bot at least 15 minuts.

I realized a simple Echo Bot. The bot messaging endpoint **isn't** Azure. The bot **is not** published, but can be added to Skype contacts. I use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

Any help is welcome. Sorry for my bad English

[image]

Comment: There is nothing built into bot framework that will allow you to do this. it may be possible via the skype API, but I do not see anything that will allow you to do this on the Skype end either.  Did you find anything that led you to believe this was possible, or is it just because it is possible on other channels you were hoping you could on Skype too?

Comment: Just because it is possible on other channels. Thanks

Comment: @JasonSowers Skype API alive? [Here](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/skype) it is writen that Skype API is no longer publicly available. I'm found only about [Skype URI API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skypeuris/skypeuriapireference).

Comment: Looks like you are correct, I was looking at our internal skype api.